# Can displaying an alert within an i html tag click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a photo upload in PHP, CSS and JavaScript. When I select the photos that I should upload from the multiple file selector I display them, I try to display every image with a close red icon illustrated by an `<i>` tag element delivered by Font-awesome.

```
<li>
  <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x close_photo" style="color: red" id="delete"></i>
  <img src="">
</li>
```

Here's an image to illustrate the situation:

[image]

The problem is when I try to click this element to delete the picture, there's no reaction after my action. I've tried so many JavaScript solutions:

```
$('#delete').on('click',function(){
    alert('OK');
});

$('#delete').click(function(){
    alert('OK');
});

$(this).trigger('click',function(){
   alert('OK');
});
```

So any one to help?

Comment: Did you try like this?

`$('li').on('click','#delete',function(){
    alert('OK');
});`

Answer (score 4):

You may need event delegation. Try like following.

```
$('body').on('click', '#delete',function(){
    alert('OK');
});
```

Comment: To explain, Kubi, those `li` elements are probably being added dynamically which means they need to be assigned event listeners once added to the page.  Instead of doing that, the code Azim provided here technically waits for the `body` to be clicked.

Comment: Yes,  you're right, the elements are automatically added. Thank's for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the id. The Id should become unique for each `<i>` tag. In this problem I think you should select the corresponding `<i>` tag using the class.

```
$("li").each(function(){
      $(this).hide();
  });
```